# onClick vb.net function but prevent postback for JavaScript

Tags: vb.net, postback, linkbutton, process.start

I have seen various examples that use a onClientClick to avoid postback.
However, I don't want this. I want to contain the linkbutton's links within vb.net code and prevent the page from performing a postback when clicked. The reason for this is when my page loads it sets the default show() and hide() div displays again which loses the user's current spot on the page when the new window opens. So how can I do this without causing the main page from resetting?

I have tried `OnClientClick="javascript:return false;"` but prevented user from clicking linkbutton.

I have also tried `AutoPostBack = "false"` and it didn't work

Attempted other ways as well. ... no luck... including trying HyperLink but those gave me issues too.

```
<asp:linkbutton ID="aCapShip" runat="server" OnClick="aCapShip_Click" style="text-decoration:none;" >
    <i class="fa glyphicon glyphicon-plane fa-lg"></i>  Cap Shipping  <!--<span class="arrow"></span>-->                              
</asp:linkbutton>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#shipping").show();
        $("#Ul2List").hide();
        $("#manufacture").hide();
        $("#Ul1List").hide();
        $("#reList").hide();

      .........
```

VB.net

```
Protected Sub aCapShip_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim url As String = "http://dummyinfo/dummyinfo/dummyinfo.aspx"
    Process.Start(url)

End Sub
```

Comment: you have to have a postback in order to run the vb code on the server from a webform control.  otherwise, you can call a url with jquery/javascript directly using standard html elements (no `runat:server` in the element)

Comment: so is there anyway to only run the JavaScript show() and hide() once? @ps2goat

Comment: you can look into update panels for an easy implementation. this still uses viewstate, but it may not be an issue for you.  An `<asp:UpdatePanel>` allows you to wrap elements, and then those elements can do postbacks without the page reloading completely. here's an example, but it may not be up-to-date with the version of .NET you are using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398867.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So my work around is the following:

VB.net

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        startUp()
End If

Public Sub startUp()
    Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">startSort()<" & "/" & "SCRIPT>")
End Sub
```

JavaScript

```
$(function startSort() {
        $("#shipping").show();
        $("#Ul2List").hide();
        $("#manufacture").hide();
        $("#Ul1List").hide();
        $("#reworkList").hide();
 });
```